# How do I access a variable from my code in Godot's editor?

Tags: godot

In Godot, I have a node with a variable that I often need to tweak for balancing purposes. It would be a lot easier to manage if I could modify it inside the editor instead of the code.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done with the [`export`](https://godot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#exports) keyword.

```
export var my_var = 5

# No default value
export(int) var my_int
```

The result of this code in the editor is this:

[image]

It is possible to use pretty much any type used in the engine as can be seen in the [documentation](https://godot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#exports). This means that you could set a scene resource to be instanced from the editor instead of hard-coding it in.

Comment: I am curious. Does Godot have a feature like Unity to set the accepted ranges, like `export var may_var = 5 #[0, 10]`?

Comment: @Drew I took a quick look at the documentation and it doesn't seem like this is currently possible. It definitely seems like a useful feature though. I wonder if anyone would be interested implementing it...

Comment: It is possible to add a range for the editor: export(type, min, max, step)

Comment: Better documentation link: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html .